# Hide create and edit button from move lines in stock picking

Tags: button, xpath, hide, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to hide the create and edit button from the model stock.picking
I already hide it from invoices but when I try to do it in picking like this

```
<record id="picking_view_inherit_duvan1" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.picking.custom2</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='move_lines']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="options">{'no_create_edit':True,'no_create':True,'no_open':True}</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="options">{'no_create_edit':True,'no_create':True,'no_open':True}</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Appears the following error

```
Element '<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='move_lines']/tree/field[@name='product_id']">' cannot be located in parent view
```

Apparently doesn't find the product_id, I also tried changing the /tree/field for /kanban/field and allow me to upgrade the module but doesn't work neither to hide the create and edit button so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

What I had to do was the following

I have to change the model from stock.picking to stock.move because the move lines are from there and also change the ref to stock.view_move_picking_tree like the following code and it work!

```
<record id="picking_view_inherit_duvan1" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">my.picking.custom2</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_move_picking_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="options">{'no_create_edit':True,'no_create':True,'no_open':True}</attribute>
           </xpath>
        </field>
</record>
```

Here is the answer in the Odoo Forum. https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/hide-the-create-and-edit-button-from-product-id-in-move-lines-stock-picking-159503.